# Correction to inverse square law for cosmology

Tags: cosmology, spectroscopy, quasars

While reading about the discovery of quasars and the spectroscopic analysis of 3C 273 in [this paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1964ApJ...140....1G&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf) by Maarten Schmidt, I came across the following quote:

> At these distances, corrections to luminosities depend on the specific world model. For
>   an approximate determination of the fluxes in the emission lines we use the formulae
>   given by Sandage (1961) based on Mattig (1958). For the energy contained within an
>   emission line, in which we integrate over the entire profile, the correction to the inverse square law is of the form $(1 + z/2)^2$
>   if the cosmological constant and deceleration parameter are zero. It is $(1 + z)^2$
>   for the steady-state model.

First, why is a correction to the inverse square law necessary? Is it to do with interstellar extinction?

Second, why are the two models different? I understand what the cosmological constant and deceleration parameter are, but why is the redshift prediction for a steady state model twice as much as when $\Lambda=q=0$?

Comment: Isn't the correction needed to account for expansion?

Comment: Ok, to account for expansion. But why? And why is it half of the steady-state?

Comment: Expansion must be accounted as for energy flux is considered. So we have the geometrical inverse square and reddening of photons. For why this is more relevant in steady state I can only think of some time dilation due to density. When photons leaves from the source in a steady state world they travel in a denser universe as compared to an expanding one. But it's a guess. I have just asked recently if gravitational shift is included in cosmological shift or is negligible or cancel out at emission & reception places but I did not get an answer.  One should really look for the works mentioned.

Comment: Just related but some links might be useful https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184115/explain-relationship-between-angular-diameter-distance-and-luminosity-distance